# Why row_number is not working with Null value for same records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, partition, row-number

I am trying to apply row number for one of query where multiple rows are there for same ID.

For example, [this is what I have as table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s02VE.png)

Now, when I use `row_number over partition` by using this code:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Race, ethnicity, Awards 
                   ORDER BY EnthnictyID ASC)
```

I am getting this:

[image: This is what I am getting after applying ROW_NUM]

There are millions of records which has same issue.

In short, I would like to replace Null with value and one thing is confirmed that all IDs has their own Race, Ethnicity and Awards so all should have value in their respective columns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

But I would like to see this `ROW_NUMBER`:

[image: Final Result with Value in Ethnicity]

Solution I have applied.

1. Using `MIN`, `MAX` and `GROUP BY` but it did work for some not for others.
2. By calling only `ROW_NUMBER = 1` it returned duplicates with `NULL` and one with a value.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Maybe you just want `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Race DESC, ethnicity DESC, Awards DESC)` the exact logic required is unclear.

Comment: I think he wants to pre-fill ethnicity from another row where it's set for same ID, and then do this row_number thingy

Comment: I think you're thinking too much in excel. What's next row? There's no such things in sql, rows aren't ordered automatically unless you specify how. Also, what happens if next row has NULL too. And what happens if you have multiple NULLs in various columns.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting two distinct row numbers because NULL is not equal to 'White'. In fact, NULL is not equal to anything else, not even NULL, that's why there is `IS [NOT] NULL` construct. So, because the engine sees White and NULL as two distinct values, you get two distinct partitions in the windowing function.

If you're just trying to use some kind of uniform default value for when a column is NULL, you can wrap that column in `ISNULL(..., <default_value>)`, for example:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Race, ISNULL(Ethnicity, 'White'), Awards ORDER BY EnthnictyID ASC)
```

This will make any Ethnicity that is NULL to be equal to 'White'. Alternatively, if the Ethnicity is missing, you might want to equal it to race:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Race, ISNULL(Ethnicity, Race), Awards ORDER BY EnthnictyID ASC)
```

This is more dynamic, because if you have a row with Race = Black, Ethnicity = NULL, it's going to partition that row into the same partinion as Race = Black, Ethnicity = Black, instead of Race = Black, Ethnicity = White that you'd get with the default constant in `ISNULL(Ethnicity, 'White')`.

Now if you're trying to identify duplicates per ID, and find out which of the rows has most columns filled in, then get rid of the rest, you probably want to partition by ID, and then order by however many not null columns you have, which would be slightly different:

```
SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
                          ORDER BY IIF(Race IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) 
                                 + IIF(Ethnicity IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)   
                                 + IIF(Awards IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)
                              DESC) AS rn

  FROM yourTable
```

As I did here, you can use all sorts of expressions in your `PARTITION BY` or `ORDER BY` clauses, here I'm ordering by the count of not null fields basically (each not null value generates a 1, null value generates a 0).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

I tried with order by as you said but throwing same result.

What exactly I want here is; I want to replace null value with value in same column not from RACE.

For example in screen shot you can see next value (second Row) is WHITE under Ethnicity so I would like to group by and replace NULL value with WHITE. This is how it will be giving single row with all values in columns.

Hope you got it!

Thanks